# Syfmony Group By Error on Sub Select

Tags: mysql, symfony

In Symfony 2 I am attempting to do a sub select to grab a total count from a table. I am getting the following error each time: `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row`. Why is the GROUP BY in my statement not working?

```
$dql = " SELECT u.id as UserId, (
                          SELECT  count(mtp.id)
                          FROM    Site\MyBundle\Entity\MessageThread mtp
                          WHERE   mtp.status=0
                          GROUP BY mtp.message
                    ) as MessageThreadCountPending
                    FROM      Site\UserBundle\Entity\Entity\User u
                    WHERE     u.id=:id
                    ";
```

Example MessageThread Table

```
id | message | status | text 
-------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 0      | Blah blah blah
2  | 2       | 0      | Blah blah blah
3  | 2       | 0      | Blah blah blah
4  | 3       | 0      | Blah blah blah
```

Desired result would by 3

Thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 1):

One easy fix is to get rid of the `group by` in the subquery:

```
SELECT u.id as UserId,
       (SELECT count(mtp.id)
        FROM Site\MyBundle\Entity\MessageThread mtp
        WHERE mtp.status = 0
       ) as MessageThreadCountPending
FROM Site\UserBundle\Entity\Entity\User u
WHERE u.id = :id;
```

Although this fixes the symptom, I suspect that you want some sort of correlation clause in the subquery.  I would guess something like this:

```
        WHERE mtp.status = 0 and mtp.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: Yeah I need that GROUP BY or else my count is out of whack. The result is all the records are counted instead of a group count based upon the mtp.message

Comment: You should edit your question with sample data and desired results.  The `group by` will generally return multiple rows, and those are not allowed in a subquery.